# argo workflow - error evaluating expression

Tags: argo

I have an error with the use of when in my pipeline
Here is my workflow

```
- name: pipeline
  dag:
    tasks:
      - name: getdata
        template: getdata-template

      - name: filter
        dependencies: [ getdata ]
        template: filter-template
        arguments:
          parameters:
            - name: getdata_output
              value: "{{tasks.getdata.outputs.parameters.output_info}}"
        when: "{{=jsonpath(tasks.getdata.outputs.parameters.output_info, '$.new' != []}} "
```

Here is the example output from getdata step

```
{new:[]}
```

And i get this error

```
Invalid 'when' expression ' 
{{=jsonpath(tasks.getdata.outputs.parameters.output_info, "$.new" != [] }} ': 
Invalid token: '{{=' (hint: try wrapping the affected expression in quotes ("))
```